# What has changed to using MT4 with WINE

Tags: wine, playonlinux

Please can someone help me as I am unable to install MT4 on wine anymore.  I have used linux for quite a few years now and each time i upgrade it gets more complicated to install.  There are so many commands out there that are irrelevant now as repo's dont exist etc. WINE doesn't even install in the menu system either.  I have tried lubuntu, xubuntu and now MATE 18.  Tried playonlinux, also have winetricks installed.

Hope someone can help, its driving me mad.
Thanks

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: wow that was quick.  I want to be able to install the correct version of wine that will install metatrader4.    I am sure in the past all i did was apt-get install wine.  On Netrunner if i install wine i can get MT4 to install, but i really want to come back to Ubuntu (mate).

Comment: What happens when you try installing Wine on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Many people in many forms are reporting exactly this. This is the result of a net-wide search in past week about this:

Beginning with MT4 version 600, about, extra Windows features than what has yet been implemented in 2019 with Wine in Ubuntu is necessary for the MT4 installation program to run. Running earlier versions of MT4 may easily lead to login issues (ie, MT4 reporting 'No connection'). (If you could get an earlier MT4 issued by the exact brokerage, it may however work.)

Some claim that by extra installation of .net features through WineTricks, and extra .DLL's, they are able to address some of the issues that are reported, but I have seen no claim that it solves the entire set of issues with MT4 installation in Wine.

The best bet, I believe (as suggested in another answer on AskUbuntu) is this: it is the installation program that requires new hard-to-get features of Wine. The resulting program, after proper initialization, may run perfectly well in standard Wine, if copied to Ubuntu and opened in Wine. Credits for this trick: [Wine doesn't run Metatrader 4 | asks for Proxy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073192/wine-doesnt-run-metatrader-4-asks-for-proxy)